# Assign value to array in bash

Tags: bash

I am learning shell sripting and got stuck. here is the code
       #!/bin/bash

```
a=0
myarray[$a]=$1
echo $myarray[$a]
((a+=1))
echo $a
```

Output:

```
#./varcheck sa
sa[0]
1
```

somebody please tell me why the name of array is getting replaced with argument that I want to assign to 0th index of array.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays#Using_Arrays-1

Answer (score 4):

```
echo "${myarray[$a]}"
```

is how you output an array member. Alternatively

```
echo "${myarray[a]}"
```

since the index is guaranteed to be arithmetic context unless you're using associative arrays. Thus, you could actually remove a line:

```
a=0
myarray[a]=$1
echo "${myarray[a++]}" # Get element at zeroth index
echo $a # Get post-incremented expansion of a.
```